# App crash when delete cell Item with custom Button (CoreData)

Tags: core-data, uicollectionview, swift4, ios12, swift4.2

When i'm delete cell from my CollectionView app is crashed (CoreData).

I'm use custom button in CollectionView.

```
var cardItems = [NSManagedObject]()

cell.MenuButton.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
cell.MenuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MenuCell), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
```

**Error**

[image]

**EDIT (It's work)**

```
let i: Int = (sender.layer.value(forKey: "index")) as! Int

guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
let itemToDelete = self.cardItems[indexPath.item]
self.cardItems.remove(at: indexPath.item)
managedContext.delete(itemToDelete)
appDelegate.saveContext()

self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Just add a tag for your button `cell.MenuButton.tag = indexPath.row` then in your action pass your button and read like `let item = cardItems[sender.tag]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not a good way to identify the click button. Instead, you can set button tag as indexPath.row like below:

```
menuButton.tag = indexPath.row
cell.MenuButton.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "index")
```

Also improve your coding skills see below:

```
cell.MenuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickMenuButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Implement this selector as:

```
let i: Int = (sender.layer.value(forKey: "index")) as! Int

func onClickMenuButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let task = self.cardItems[sender.tag]
       if let managedContext = task.managedObjectContext {
              managedContext.delete(task)
              do {
                 try managedContext.save()
                 self.cardItems.remove(at: sender.tag)
                 let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
                 self.collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
              } catch {
                 print("Failed to delete")
              }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array `indexPaths` does not have any value. It is because there is no collection view items which are in selected state

You can select first collection view item programmatically as follows :

```
let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first ?? IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
```

Comment: Thank you. How fix that?

Comment: I don't need to delete only the first cell. I need to delete the one in which I clicked on the "delete" button